# Arrow functions and brackets

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So just something that I don't understand, and this could be a problem with my general javascript and es6 knowledge.

```
export const foo = (x,y) => { expression }
```

returns `null`

while `export const foo = (x,y) => expression`

returns the object I was looking for

Comment: The first one actually returns `undefined`.

Comment: [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions - Information can all be found here. If you're using curly brackets, you must explicitly return a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the brackets you must use the word `return` to explicitly return something. Implicit return only works when there is a single statement and no brackets.

```
export const foo = (x,y) => { return expression }
```

Comment: Perfect, thx for your input

Comment: @apttap  - dont forget to mark it as the correct answer.